# Uploading to Sketchfab

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, export

I'm new to 3D modeling but familiar with Sketchfab and the model creation process through photogrammetry. I'm trying to create realistic transparent clouds in Blender using the Cloud Generator plugin:
[[image: Cloud Generator]

They look great in Cycles renderer. I've unwrapped UVs from the cloud mesh and saved the image as a .png. I've uploaded the model using the integrated uploader in Blender, and I've manually added the .png in Sketchfab, but all I get is something that looks like this:
[[image: Sketchfab cloud]

I've also tried enabling "automatically pack into .blend" in Blender as [described in this Sketchfab article](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/209143886-Blender-Materials). The final effect I'm going for is something [like this cloud.](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/209143886-Blender-Materials)

Comment: You can't just unwrap a mesh and expect Cycles volumetric shaders to be exported to some random web viewer

Comment: x2 :D..........

Answer (score 1):

Sketchfab does not always show the image of your model as published but reverts it to the original state before you modeled it in their viewer, looking for an answer to this issue also but till then I have been using this method to be sure the viewers see the work product I wish to show.
I have been using screenshots loaded to google storage and adding a link
above the model description .

Answer (score 1):

Cloud generator always work with VOLUME shader in Blender. Sketchfab canot read into the VOLUME shader, since it's different from a surface (material) shader.
If you need to create a sketchfab cloud you may use CARDS (grids) and you should generate them within blender. Then on Sketchfab assign the material using transparency. Sketchfab has a guide on which materials it can be picked up.